Simple REINFORCE-like algorithm not learning
I'm trying to fully understand how the REINFORCE algorithm is used to update the weights of a network. In the process I've isolated it to the simplest possible example - Sampling on a single parameter network and trying to move that parameter to get higher rewards. However, no matter what I try the gradients are zero and the parameter is not being updated. What am I doing wrong?
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class SimplestNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.param = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([1.0]))

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.param.expand(x.size(0))

model = SimplestNetwork()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

for step in range(1001):
    batch_size = 1000
    means = model(torch.ones(batch_size))
    stds = torch.ones_like(means)
    dist = torch.distributions.Normal(means, stds)
    actions = dist.rsample()
    log_probs = dist.log_prob(actions)
    rewards = -torch.exp(actions).detach()  # Proper REINFORCE detach

    loss = -(log_probs * rewards).mean()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    if step % 100 == 0:
        print(f"Step: {step}")
        print(f"Param: {model.param.item():.10f}")
        print(f"Mean action: {actions.mean().item():.6f}")
        print(f"Mean reward: {rewards.mean().item():.6f}")
        print(f"Loss: {loss.item():.6f}")
        print(f"Grad: {model.param.grad}")  # Will be None here since we zeroed after backward

